# Q number format vs IEEE 754 format?

Tags: dsp-core

I'm reading up on DSP implementations and [Q number format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28number_format%29) for representing decimal and decimal fractional numbers. Why would you use the Q format and not a standard like [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)? When would you use one instead of the other? They both encode numbers into a sequence of bits, right?

Comment: This is a good question. I think some detailed explanations can be given, even though as mentioned in the below posts the short answer is - "Q notation is for fixed point arithmetic for processors (typically microcontrollers with DSP applications) and IEEE 754 is for floating point arithmetic on more powerful processors with a dedicated FPU (floating point unit) as a coprocessor".

Answer (score 8):

Q format numbers are fixed-point, which means they can be manipulated by integer ALUs, rather than needing to use a floating-point unit.  In a DSP setting, this is useful for greater speed and lower power consumption, since fixed-point arithmetic is much simpler than floating-point.  On the other hand, the main advantage of using a floating-point representation is greater dynamic range.

Answer (score 5):

Addition and subtraction usimg floating point representations requires a normalization step at the end, which requires more instructions in a software FP implementation and more transistors and longer (thus probably having higher electrical capacitance) wires in a hardware implementation.  Thus, depending on the DSP implementation, using floating point may incur a higher transistor, time and/or energy cost over scaled integer formats that do not require a normalization step.

However, many modern processors have such fast floating point (or slow integer multiplies) that this difference may be impossible to measure, or even negative.

Comment: The last sentence is the key. Fixed-point processing is commonly done in embedded DSP processors and FPGAs, but signal processing done on powerful platforms like PCs/servers is typically done all in floating-point (in many cases with single-precision floats instead of double, for speed).